# I need to extract data from specific part from a given PDF and need to store those extracted parts in MySQL data base table,

Tags: asp.net

I need to extract data from specific part from a given PDF and need to store those extracted parts in MySQL data base table, I have written function, to read coordinates of location in given pdf, but in my function, it overrides previous content and will return, last value.

Any way to get values without overriding it?

using (var reader = new PdfReader(@"D:\DMS@#\A\ABC.pdf"))
{

```
            var parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);

            var strategy = parser.ProcessContent(1, new LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition());

            var res = strategy.GetLocations();

            reader.Close();
            List<string> oPDFDATA = new List<string>();
            
            
            PDFDATA oPDFDATADTO = new PDFDATA();
```

it should shows "oPDFDATADTO" in , like
name:-name;
Age:- age;
city:-cityt

```
            //var searchResult = res.Where(p => p.Text.Contains("name")).OrderBy(p => p.Y).Reverse().ToList();
            //oPDFDATA<name>= searchResult.ToString();

            oPDFDATADTO.Name = res.Where(p => p.Text.Contains("Name")).OrderBy(p => p.Y).Reverse().Select(x => x.Text).ToString();
            oPDFDATADTO.Age = res.Where(p => p.Text.Contains("Age")).OrderBy(p => p.Y).Reverse().Select(x => x.Text).ToString();
            oPDFDATADTO.City = res.Where(p => p.Text.Contains("City")).OrderBy(p => p.Y).Reverse().Select(x => x.Text).ToString();
            oPDFDATA.Add(oPDFDATADTO.ToString());

            oPDFDATADTO.Name = oPDFDATA[0];
            oPDFDATADTO.Age = oPDFDATA[0];
            oPDFDATADTO.City = oPDFDATA[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is that you should write

```
oPDFDATA.Last()
```

or

```
oPDFDATA[oPDFDATA.Length - 1]
```

to get the last element in your array.

A more elaborate question would address the whole algorythm you've written as it seems you're taking too many steps as you serialize and deserialize the very same data in two consecutive steps, why not just converting them directly?. Also, these two variables look like containing pretty much the same bit of data to me:

```
oPDFDATADTO.Age = oPDFDATA[0];
oPDFDATADTO.City = oPDFDATA[0];
```

Cheers.

Comment: please help me, I have a PDF file, I need to extract specific lines from PDF and then store that extracted content in MySQL data base table.  I tried too many ways, I used itext sharp library